# set background image for a state/template in angularjs?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I tried putting a div tag around the whole template and styling it with css like

```
<div ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(/images/food.png)', 'background-repeat': 'repeat-y'}">
    <img src="/images/final.png" class="brandImg center-block">
    <h3 class="text-center"> Please Enter your Registered Mobile Number to Login</h3>

    <form novalidate name="CSloginForm" ng-submit="loginCustomer()" role="form" class="csLoginForm col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-offset-1">
            <label for="phno" style="font: 22px sans-serif;">Mobile No</label>
            <input type="tel" name="phno" id="phno" style="margin-left: 60px; width: 300px; margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 20px" class="phInput" ng-maxlength="10" ng-minlength="10" ng-model="csNumber" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" ng-disabled="CSloginForm.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg col-xs-offset-9" ng-click="csLookUp()" style="margin-bottom: 10px">Start</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

but this only puts background in a header part of the Page not the whole page?

Comment: in which `div` you have used

Comment: top div which is coming as a separate line on top

Comment: is others `div` is inside that `div` or what ? can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: Is that the whole page? No?

Comment: yes,its a template page on a certain URL

Comment: Can you create a snippet or a fiddle or something? This is not quite reproducible now. What do you mean by "a header part"?

Comment: At least it seems that you're missing a few closing tags.

Comment: see there is a header part which consist of brand logo and a message and then there is form to take customer contact number

Comment: You have provided incomplete details, to me it looks like CSS issue. Not sure what role angular has to play in it. I almost want to down vote the question. Give proper problem statement with full code, preferably fiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$rootScope`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope) for this. Object in the root scope are propagated to all child scopes.

```
angular.module('app').run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.app = { background-image: 'url(/images/default.png)' };
});
```

Now in your base HTML template you add the background to the body (not a div).

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body ng-style="{'background-image': app.background, 'background-repeat': 'repeat-y'}">
     ...
  </body>
```

Given that the view has a controller

```
<div ng-controller="PageCtrl">
  ..
</div>
```

You can access `app` and set the background from the controller

```
angular.module('app').controller('PageCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.app.background = 'url(/images/food.png)';
});
```

You can set the background in a view without a controller using [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit), but this is discouraged.